# Outside click of input field not working in react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, events

I am trying to hide the field when user click on outside the input field and show the field when user click on input field. I have seen some example on stackoverflow where they said to use `e.stopPropagation()` I did it but still in my case its not working. I don't know whats I am doing wrong.

Here is my code.

```
 class TodoApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.pasteRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      showPastePopup: false,
      fname: ''
    }
  }

  onPasteClick = () =>{
    this.setState({
      showPastePopup: false
    })
  }

  closePastePopup = e => {

    console.log("called")
    this.setState({
      showPastePopup:false
    }) 
  }

  showPastePopup = e => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    let posx = e.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft + 
        document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    let posy = e.clientY + document.body.scrollTop + 
        document.documentElement.scrollTop;

    this.pasteRef.current.style.left = posx + "px";
    this.pasteRef.current.style.top = posy + "px";

    this.setState({
      showPastePopup: true,
    })
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Todos: Some text will be here.........</h2>
        <span id="pasteBox" ref={this.pasteRef} onClick={this.onPasteClick} className={this.state.showPastePopup ? "showCopyBox control" : "hideCopyBox control"}>
          paste
        </span>
        <div id="pasteArea" className="col w-50 border border-success " onClick={this.closePastePopup}>

          <div className="mt-1">
            First Name: <input onMouseUp={this.showPastePopup}  value={this.state.fname || ''} type="text"     id="fname" name="fname" /> {this.state.fname}

          </div>
          <br/>
          <div className="mt-1">
            Last Name: <input onMouseUp={this.showPastePopup} value='' type="text" id="lname" name="lname" />

          </div>
          <br/>
          <div className="mt-1">
            Address: <input onMouseUp={this.showPastePopup} value='' type="text" id="add" name="add" /> 

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TodoApp />, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

If I comment on `closePastePopup()` then its show the popup but how can close the popup if user click outside of the input tag?

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my [jsfiddke](https://jsfiddle.net/zafarn8/ua1p7gwk/26/)

Comment: I don't understand what you want but if it's just about focus in and out of an input there is `onfocusin` and `onfocusout` event for this

Comment: @QuentinGrisel thanks for replay.Actually I am looking for when user click on input tag then my span tag should display and when user click outside the input tag or click on paste then span tag should hide.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using the different types of events, if you write onClick or onMouseUp for both elements, it works.
The stopPropagation method stops only the current event.

Comment: thanks for reply and appreciate for your time. Yes its working if I used same type event. But why it's not working for different event type? Can you just edit the answer and explain in details so that I can accept your answer.Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

You didn't pass e to methods and didn't bind them in constructor.

Constructor should look like this:

```
    constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.pasteRef = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      showPastePopup: false,
      fname: ''
    }
    this.onPasteClick = this.onPasteClick.bind(this);
    this.closePastePopup = this.closePastePopup.bind(this);
    this.showPastePopup = this.showPastePopup.bind(this);
  }
```

And when you invoke methods:

```
<input onMouseUp={e => this.showPastePopup(e)} value='' type="text" id="add" name="add" />
```

Comment: @Sa1mOn thanks for replay. I don't think that is the issue because I am using arrow function and dont need to bind. anyways I did the changes as per your suggestions but still issue is the same.